# Changing order of integration in triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Change the order of integration in the triple integral
> $$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^y f(x,y,z) \,dz ~dy~dx$$
> to $dz~dx~dy$

**Attempt:** Here, since $z$ remains in the same place I think it is enough to consider only what happens in the $xy$ plane. So the bounds will become $0 \leq y \leq 1$, $y \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq z \leq y$. However, my intuition tells me that this is not correct since if we change the order of $x$ and $y$ then this will affect $z$ as well. So is my intuition correct? If yes then how can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just focus on $x$ and $y$, as $z$ is not changing its position. Then,

Original:
$$\color{red}{0\le x\le1,\space 0\le y\le x},\space 0\le z\le y$$
Alternative:
$$\color{red}{y\le x\le1,\space 0\le y\le 1},\space 0\le z\le y$$

So you can change the integral to
$$\int_0^1 \int_y^1 \int_0^y f(x,y,z) \,dz~dx~dy$$

Comment: So my initial solution was correct, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Great! Thanks for clarifying!